# resize span container on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

How do I get the `.container` to `resize` it's height when the `span` content is shown on `:hover`? As you can see the `text` inside of the `span` overlaps the `.container` causing a glitch when hovering between the two `.text` inputs.

I want the `.container` to resize it's height to match what's showing in the `span` after `:hover`.

```css
.share {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fc2757;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-right: -3px;
  transition: all 300ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

.first {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.last {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

.container:hover .icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.container:hover .icon span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.container:hover .label {
  opacity: 0;
}

.container:hover .deal {
  background: #3b5998;
}

.container:hover .buzz {
  background: #007bb5;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  border: 3px solid green;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.content svg {
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.text {
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="share">
    <div class="icon deal first"><span class="content">
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 94.638 94.638" width="30" height="30"><path d="M21.531 54.713L39.29 72.472l32.583-32.583L54.115 22.13 21.531 54.713zm70.993-24.39l-7.556-7.557a10.088 10.088 0 0 1-4.841 1.231c-5.591 0-10.123-4.532-10.123-10.122 0-1.753.448-3.402 1.232-4.841l-7.557-7.557a5.074 5.074 0 0 0-7.157 0L1.478 56.524a5.075 5.075 0 0 0 0 7.156l7.558 7.557a10.085 10.085 0 0 1 4.841-1.23c5.591 0 10.122 4.53 10.122 10.121 0 1.753-.447 3.402-1.232 4.842l7.557 7.557a5.077 5.077 0 0 0 7.158 0l55.044-55.046a5.077 5.077 0 0 0-.002-7.158zM39.29 80.595L13.41 54.713l40.707-40.705 25.879 25.881L39.29 80.595z" fill="#fff"/></svg><p class="text">Deal Item</p></span></div>
    <div class="icon buzz last">
      <span class="content"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 94.638 94.638" width="30" height="30"><path d="M78.2 48.916a3.647 3.647 0 0 1 0-3.195l3.355-6.866a3.639 3.639 0 0 0-1.565-4.814l-6.75-3.58a3.634 3.634 0 0 1-1.877-2.588l-1.321-7.529a3.637 3.637 0 0 0-4.094-2.973l-7.569 1.07a3.642 3.642 0 0 1-3.038-.986l-5.495-5.313a3.64 3.64 0 0 0-5.061 0l-5.495 5.313a3.634 3.634 0 0 1-3.038.986l-7.569-1.07a3.635 3.635 0 0 0-4.09 2.973l-1.321 7.529a3.644 3.644 0 0 1-1.878 2.587l-6.753 3.58a3.64 3.64 0 0 0-1.561 4.815l3.355 6.866a3.647 3.647 0 0 1 0 3.195l-3.355 6.867a3.639 3.639 0 0 0 1.564 4.814l6.75 3.58a3.644 3.644 0 0 1 1.878 2.588l1.32 7.528a3.637 3.637 0 0 0 4.095 2.973l7.568-1.07a3.642 3.642 0 0 1 3.039.986l5.494 5.313a3.64 3.64 0 0 0 5.062 0l5.495-5.313a3.634 3.634 0 0 1 3.038-.986l7.569 1.07a3.637 3.637 0 0 0 4.093-2.973l1.321-7.528a3.644 3.644 0 0 1 1.878-2.588l6.75-3.58a3.642 3.642 0 0 0 1.565-4.814l-3.36-6.867zM40.04 69.152l8.9-16.965-14.555-7.263 20.214-19.438-8.901 16.95 14.552 7.263-20.21 19.453z" fill="#fff"/></svg><p class="text">Buzz Item</p></span></div>
    <div class="label">Create</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may try the `onmousehover` property. Upon hover event, it can call a method that would change the size of your container.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like it to be like a navbar?

```
<div class = "topnav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a class = "active" href = "Anime.html">Home</a></li>
          <li>
            <div class = "dropdown">
            <a href = "Preise.html"><button onclick = "myFunction()" class = "dropbtn">Preise</button></a>
              <i class = "fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            <div class = "dropdown-content">
              <a href = "yugi.html">Yugi</a>
              <a href = "atemu.html">Atemu</a>
              <a href = "kaiba.html">Kaiba</a>
              <a href = "sebastian.html">Sebastian</a>
              <a href = "ciel.html">Ciel</a>
              <a href = "undertaker.html">Undertaker</a>
              <a href = "izuku.html">Izuku</a>
              <a href = "ochako.html">Ochako</a>
              <a href = "kazuki.html">Katsuki</a>
              <a href = "Preise.html">Preise</a>
              <a href = "weiterecharaktere.html">Weitere Charaktere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href = "bestellformular.html">Bestellformular</a></li>
          <li><a href = "impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      </div>
```

I copied that from my own code so you will have to edit it.

```html
        nav ul {list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
nav ul li {display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
       text-align: center;
}
.button {font-size: 16px;}


.topnav {overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
}
.topnav a {float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16 px;
}
.topnav a:hover {background-color: #ddd;
       color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {background-color: #caffee;
        color: black;
}
.dropdown {float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {font-size: 20px; 
       border: none;
       outline: none;
       color: #f2f2f2;
       padding: 14px 16px;
       background-color: inherit;
       font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
       margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */}
/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn { background-color: red;
}
/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content { display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     min-width: 160px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a { float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
}
/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover { background-color: #ddd;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { display: block;
}
```

That should work although I´m not sure if it´s what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the bar is, *essentially*, determined by the height of the icons

```
.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

The absolute positioning of the `label` means that there is no change to the height when the container is hovered.

So, you have a couple of alternatives, either remove the absolute positioning and refactor your HTML/CSS to accomodate this change or for a *quick and dirty solution*, just change the height of the icon when the hover kicks in.

```
.container:hover .icon {
  height:100px;
}
```

The labels will still be absolutely positioned by the container will *apparently* expand to accomdate them although, in fact, that is not the case.

NOtEL: this will cause problems with the "circle" shapes becoming an oval which is why I would recommend the first option...but that's a longer story.

```css
.share {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fc2757;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-right: -3px;
  transition: all 300ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

.first {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.last {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

.container:hover .icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container:hover .icon span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.container:hover .label {
  opacity: 0;
}

.container:hover .deal {
  background: #3b5998;
}

.container:hover .buzz {
  background: #007bb5;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  border: 3px solid green;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.content svg {
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.text {
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="share">
    <div class="icon deal first"><span class="content">
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 94.638 94.638" width="30" height="30"><path d="M21.531 54.713L39.29 72.472l32.583-32.583L54.115 22.13 21.531 54.713zm70.993-24.39l-7.556-7.557a10.088 10.088 0 0 1-4.841 1.231c-5.591 0-10.123-4.532-10.123-10.122 0-1.753.448-3.402 1.232-4.841l-7.557-7.557a5.074 5.074 0 0 0-7.157 0L1.478 56.524a5.075 5.075 0 0 0 0 7.156l7.558 7.557a10.085 10.085 0 0 1 4.841-1.23c5.591 0 10.122 4.53 10.122 10.121 0 1.753-.447 3.402-1.232 4.842l7.557 7.557a5.077 5.077 0 0 0 7.158 0l55.044-55.046a5.077 5.077 0 0 0-.002-7.158zM39.29 80.595L13.41 54.713l40.707-40.705 25.879 25.881L39.29 80.595z" fill="#fff"/></svg><p class="text">Deal Item</p></span></div>
    <div class="icon buzz last">
      <span class="content"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 94.638 94.638" width="30" height="30"><path d="M78.2 48.916a3.647 3.647 0 0 1 0-3.195l3.355-6.866a3.639 3.639 0 0 0-1.565-4.814l-6.75-3.58a3.634 3.634 0 0 1-1.877-2.588l-1.321-7.529a3.637 3.637 0 0 0-4.094-2.973l-7.569 1.07a3.642 3.642 0 0 1-3.038-.986l-5.495-5.313a3.64 3.64 0 0 0-5.061 0l-5.495 5.313a3.634 3.634 0 0 1-3.038.986l-7.569-1.07a3.635 3.635 0 0 0-4.09 2.973l-1.321 7.529a3.644 3.644 0 0 1-1.878 2.587l-6.753 3.58a3.64 3.64 0 0 0-1.561 4.815l3.355 6.866a3.647 3.647 0 0 1 0 3.195l-3.355 6.867a3.639 3.639 0 0 0 1.564 4.814l6.75 3.58a3.644 3.644 0 0 1 1.878 2.588l1.32 7.528a3.637 3.637 0 0 0 4.095 2.973l7.568-1.07a3.642 3.642 0 0 1 3.039.986l5.494 5.313a3.64 3.64 0 0 0 5.062 0l5.495-5.313a3.634 3.634 0 0 1 3.038-.986l7.569 1.07a3.637 3.637 0 0 0 4.093-2.973l1.321-7.528a3.644 3.644 0 0 1 1.878-2.588l6.75-3.58a3.642 3.642 0 0 0 1.565-4.814l-3.36-6.867zM40.04 69.152l8.9-16.965-14.555-7.263 20.214-19.438-8.901 16.95 14.552 7.263-20.21 19.453z" fill="#fff"/></svg><p class="text">Buzz Item</p></span></div>
    <div class="label">Create</div>
  </div>
</div>
```